# How can I remove the comma after journal name and before volume in my bst description?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style

I am using an apparently heavily-edited `apalike` bst style, which I have to use for some reason.

This style unfortunately outputs a comma between the journal name and the volume number, which is something I need to avoid.

Here are the supposedly relevant code snippets:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output              % special for
  output.year.check                 % apalike
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
{ format.article.crossref output.nonnull
  format.pages output
}
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { " (" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
    { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * 
warning$ }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
%   { pop$ format.pages }
    { ": " * pages n.dashify * }
%   { ", " * pages n.dashify * }    % changed from ":" for vol,pgs -- BJR 10/5/89
    { ": " * pages n.dashify * }    % changed from ":" for vol,pgs -- BJR 10/5/89
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

How can I remove this comma with the least amount of changes to this code? To summarize again, I would like to have

> Author names (year) Title of article. Journal Name Volume (Number): pages

instead of

> Author names (year) Title of article. Journal Name, Volume (Number): pages

EDIT: The full file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/RZmmiqyh

EDIT2: I am particularly in search of a solution that can also handle entries that are "in press", i.e. neither volume, nor number, nor pages have been assigned yet. Instead, after the journal name a colon should appear, and after the colon a comment such as "in press" should be printed.

Example:

> Author names (year) Title of article. Journal Name: in press

Exemplary Bibtex entry:

```
@Article{Author2018,
  Title                    = {How to make Bibtex do what I want},
  Author                   = {Adrian A. Author},
  Journal                  = {Journal of Bibtexing},
  Year                     = {2018},
  Note                     = {in press},
}
```

Comment: Can you upload the entire `.bst` file to a text-sharing website like pastebin (please don't use a file sharing website where one has to download a `.zip` or the like)? That would make it much easier to actually test a solution and it helps with the definitions of unseen macros like `field.or.null`.

Comment: Sure, please find it here: https://pastebin.com/RZmmiqyh

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Open your modified copy of `apalike.bst` in a text editor. (The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.)
- Immediately after the function `output.check`, add the following 3 lines of code:

  ```
  FUNCTION {add.blank}
  {  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
  }
  ```
- In the `article` function, locate the line that says

  ```
     { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
  ```
- Immediately after this line (and hence immediately before the line that says `format.vol.num.pages output`), insert a new line with following text:

  ```
       add.blank
  ```
- Save the bst file
- Rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX once more to recreate the formatted bibliography

Happy BibTeXing!

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question, about how to handle an entry which is "In press", i.e., which hasn't been published yet and for which the `volume`, `number`, and `pages` fields are not yet available.

I believe you should put the "In Press" information in the `year` field, *not* the `note` field. If the article hasn't been published yet, it's better to write "In press" in the year field; before you know it, the publication year might slip from 2018 to 2019 or even 2020... Optional: Use a `\noopsort` directive to help BibTeX  with figuring out how to sort the entry. And, place an `\unskip` directive in the entry's `volume` field to undo the output of the `add.blank` directive.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@preamble { "\providecommand\noopsort[1]{}" }
@Article{Author:InPress,
  Title     = {Thoughts},
  Author    = {Adrian A. Author},
  Journal   = {Journal of Bib\TeX{}ing},
  Year      = {\noopsort{2019}In Press},
  volume    = {\unskip},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-nocomma} % modified form of 'apalike.bst'
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked - almost. Now, there is a space between the Journal name and the colon, which should not exist.

Comment: @Michael - If there's a space between the journal name and the colon, it must be because the entry is missing the `volume` field. That's almost certainly an error. All academic journals I'm familiar with feature a `volume` number. Which journal you're citing from is missing the `volume` information?

Comment: You are right, the volume is missing here. The reason: the article is in press and no volume was assigned yet. Thus, I want the respective entry to appear as: Author names (year) Article title. Journal name: in press

Comment: @Michael - So not only the `volume` field, but also the `number` and `pages` fields, are missing? You might have volunteered this rather crucial piece of information a bit earlier...

Comment: @Michael - Please edit your posting to (a) mention that for entries the `volume`, `number`, and `pages` fields might be missing and (b) provide a representative example of such an entry. Clearly, this is a rather non-standard case which requires further investigation.

Comment: In one particular case, yes. For regular articles with volume (and number), your solution works like a charm. If I put the "in press" into the "note" field, there is no comma nor colon at all. Thus, I tried to circumvent this by putting "in press" to the "pages" field, hoping the journal name would just be followed by a colon, then followed by the "in press" instead of an actual page range...

Comment: @Michael - Please edit your query to provide a specific example of such a "non-standard" entry.

Comment: @Michael - Please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. While I understand your argument, I need to do it exactly the way I wrote - no matter if there is a (small) chance the year might become wrong.

Comment: @Michael - do you want me to delete this answer as it evidently does not help you achieve your objective?