# natbib remove comma after editors

Tags: natbib

after making a custom .bst-file with makebst i have to fine-tune part of the style.

for example i have to get rid of a comma that comes after the "(Ed.)"-field. With the help of [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451347/how-can-i-remove-the-comma-after-journal-name-and-before-volume-in-my-bst-descri) i got rid of the comma after the journal name. apperently i have no idea where to edit now to accomplish my desired modification. i tried several things but nothing worked (e.g. i got rid of commas after the title or after the booktitle.)

here is an mwe:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@incollection{label1,
    address = {city},
    author = {Doe, John},
    booktitle = {{Science 2018}},
    editor = {Best Editors},
    pages = {1-10},
    publisher = {Best Publisher},
    title = {{Data you really want}},
    year = {2019}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{mybst}

\begin{document}
\citet{label1}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

does someone know how i would have to alter the bst-file?

- edit:
  the bst file is as follows:
  https://pastecode.xyz/view/e6678495

---

SOLVED:
in line 670 the formatting function for the related type "format.in.ed.booktitle" begins. in line 681 you'll find

```
  "(" swap$ * "), " *
```

just delete the comma and you'll get to

```
  "(" swap$ * ") " *
```

with the desired outcome.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You are asking about a custom file but are requesting style `chicago` to be used. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: thank you! i used chicago as a reference style as its a standard that anyone has built-in so it would be not necessary to provide my code. the solution would be transferable to my style. if it would be helpful to deliver the specific .bst, i can do so as well

Comment: Try line 681, but i haven't tested.

Comment: of course it was line 681. why haven't i seen this before -.- thank you very much

Comment: Now try to find the same in `chicago.bst`.

Comment: protip: you cant :) sorry, didnt know that it would not be transferable